# How to apply padding, and border in div(with multiple tags)?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a 'In Construction' page in HTML, and want to make a box in div only one. and, Texts are overlap when I add tag in text. (h1, h2..)

I want to solve all of these!

I expected that texts are not overlap, and one box covers all of texts.

```css
        .text {
            padding: 30px;
            border: 3px black;
            background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
        }

        .text h1 {
            font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-align: center;

            color: white;

            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

            text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(30, 30, 30);
        }

        .text h2 {
            font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-align: center;

            color: white;

            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

            text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(30, 30, 30);
        }
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class="text">
            <h1>COMMING SOON</h1>
            <h2>ABCDE</h2>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: apply the centring with position:absolute to the parent container, not each title

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you so much! I solved it! :)